lock rotation on damped track?
I'm using Damped Track constraint for a PNG image looking at the camera (at Z axis)
I made a plane with a PNG image with alpha channel that i want to make it constantly look at the camera, and at first it looks great, but the thing is, i have it attached to a 3D model that rotates (horizontally) but when i play the animation, the PNG plane begins to move correctly until around 180º or more and the PNG plane rotates quickly like from 0 to 360 but i want it to stay still looking at the camera, how do i fix this? i have it on Z track axis.
I made an example of what is happening with some images below:

Already tried to lock rotation from the object (PNG plane) but it only works for the object rotation itself, and not when is attached (parent) to another object.
